# Refresh tab fragment page on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 3 fragment tabs in a ViewPager.

Fragment1 contains a ListFragment and Fragment2 also contains a ListFragment.

After clicking an item in Fragment2, it should go to Fragment1 and refresh the List. (The list is populated via a web service using Gson). So Fragment2 passes a value to Fragment1 so that it can reload according to the parameter carried along.

I've tried many ways to refresh/update the state of the List in Fragment1 including reloading the whole Fragment1 `onCreateView`, using `FragmentTransaction` and also calling the host `Activity` within itself. Still couldn't find a way to make it.

Also I noticed that upon scrolling to tab 3 and back to tab 1, it refreshes it. But it doesn't refresh the list from Tab 2 to Tab 1. I read a solution in SO suggests to set `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);`, still the problem persists.

Here is my code currently.

In the Host activity (`UserShopActivity`), I've implemented an interface listener from Fragment2 (`UserCategoriesFragment`) to obtain `category_id` to be passed to Fragment1 (`UserItemsFragment`):

```
public class UserShopActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        UserCategoriesFragment.OnUserCategoriesSelectedListener {

...

    @Override
    public void onUserCategoriesSelected(String category_id) {

        setTabUserItems(category_id);
        String userItemsFragment = getTabUserItems();
        UserItemsFragment uif = (UserItemsFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":0");

        if (uif == null) {
            setSaveToUserItems(category_id);
            Log.d("userItemFragment: ", "null");
        } else {
            setSaveToUserItems(category_id);
            uif.updateCat(category_id);
            Log.d("cat id sent: ", userItemsFragment);

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    }

}
```

I have successfully passed the `category_id`. Upon calling `setCurrentItem(0)`, it goes to Fragment1. This is where I want to reload the list. But how?

In the TabAdapter, I've implemented `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and override `onPageSelected` method. I believe this is where I should put the refresh coding.

I've also tried to refresh Fragment2 in this method like so:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    Log.d("onPageSelected: ", i + "");
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);

    if(i == 0) {
       UserItemsFragment uif = new UserItemsFragment();
       uif.reload();
    }
}
```

And in `reload()` something like:

```
public void reload(){
   // re-call the fragment from within itself
}
```

However, I got `nullpointerexception` error :(

Can someone point to me where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int i) {
    Log.d("onPageSelected: ", i + "");
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);

    if(i == 0) {
        UserItemsFragment frg = (UserItemsFragment)mAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, i);
        frg.reload();
    }
}
```